# Using RestTemplate with JAXB annotations: list not recognized

Tags: jaxb, resttemplate, spring-resttemplate

I'm using RestTemplate in an application server project (not Spring Boot) to get an entity from an endpoint.

The entity DTO (using JAXB annotations) is:

```
@XmlAccessorType(XmlAccessType.NONE)
@XmlRootElement(name = "entity")
public class EntityDTO {
    private Integer id; // this was missing
    private List<String> parameterName; // parameter names 

    public EntityDTO() {
    }

    @XmlElementWrapper(name = "parameterNames")
    @XmlElement(name = "parameterName")
    public List<String> getParameterName() {
        return parameterName;
    }

    public void setParameterName(List<String> parameterName) {
        this.parameterName = parameterName;
    }

    @XmlElement(name = "id")
    public Integer getId() {
        return id;
    }

    // this was returning Integer instead of void
    public void setId(Integer id) {
        this.id = id;
    }
}
```

So in the endpoint the entity is returned for example in this way:

```
{
  "entity": {
    "id": 1,
    "parameterNames": {
      "parameterName": [
        "param1",
        "param2"
      ]
    }
  }
}
```

I'm performing a GET to the previous endpoint using RestTemplate with the following code:

```
...

HttpEntity<EntityDTOO> response = restTemplate.exchange(
            uri,
            HttpMethod.GET,
            httpEntity,
            EntityDTO.class);
...
```

But RestTemplate unmarshalls the entity in this way:

```
id: 1
parameterName: null
```

But I was expecting:

```
id: 1
parameterName: ["param1", "param2"]
```

Anyone knows how to recognize the @XmlElementWrapper(name = "parameterNames") annotation using  RestTemplate?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: I don't think there's anything wrong with the annotation. Are you sure you are creating a list with elements? You might not be constructing the object appropriately.

Comment: I did find some errors in your code. I will edit your code to correct them.

Comment: I cannot proceed unless you provide more of your code. For example, what is the URI you are using to test? How did you create the `HttpEntity`? Those are very important parts and most likely where the error lies. As I mentioned before, the JAXB part works fine. You may need to create an `HttpMessageConverter` for it to work and I can't be sure unless you provide all that information.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Configure the Accept header with application/xml. You will get an xml response and a Content type header with application/xml. Then resttemplate will recognize xml without additional configuration and using the bean annotations.

Answer (score 0):

```
@XmlAccessorType(XmlAccessType.NONE)
@XmlRootElement(name = "entity")
public class EntityDTO {
    private Integer id;
    private List<String> parameterName; // parameter names

    public EntityDTO() {
    }

    @XmlElementWrapper(name = "parameterNames")
    @XmlElement(name = "parameterName")
    public List<String> getParameterName() {
        return parameterName;
    }

    public void setParameterName(List<String> parameterName) {
        this.parameterName = parameterName;
    }

    @XmlElement(name = "id")
    public Integer getId() {
        return id;
    }

    public void setId(Integer id) {
        this.id = id;
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        try {
            EntityDTO dto = new EntityDTO();
            List<String> params = new ArrayList<>();
            params.add("param1");
            params.add("param2");
            dto.setId(1);
            dto.setParameterName(params);
            JAXBContext jaxbContext = JAXBContext.newInstance(EntityDTO.class);
            Marshaller jaxbMarshaller = jaxbContext.createMarshaller();
            jaxbMarshaller.setProperty(Marshaller.JAXB_FORMATTED_OUTPUT, Boolean.TRUE);
            StringWriter sw = new StringWriter();
            jaxbMarshaller.marshal(dto, sw);
            String xmlContent = sw.toString();
            System.out.println(xmlContent);
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
```

Basically, using your `EntityDTO` class and adding parameters to the JAXB object, results in the expected XML.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="yes"?>
<entity>
    <id>1</id>
    <parameterNames>
        <parameterName>param1</parameterName>
        <parameterName>param2</parameterName>
    </parameterNames>
</entity>
```

I think the problem is that the method *`restTemplate.exchange`* is not setting the parameters list in the `EntityDTO` object. You're probably using the incorrect variant of that method.